# Changing UIToolbar UIBarMetrics

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, uitoolbar, uibarmetrics

Is there anyway to have the UIBarMetrics of a custom UIToolbar change when the device is rotated? I would prefer it happen automatically but if there is something I can do during rotation that would also be ok. I would like to use UIAppearance so manually adjusting the height of the bar won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

> UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolbar appearance];
>
> [toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbarLandscapePhone"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];

You can simple to setBarMetrics to UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone

Comment: Yes, I am setting the background image for UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone but the bar is not changing when I rotate it. It only changes if I use the toolbar from a UINavigationController. The UINavigationController must be doing something with the UIBarMetrics that is not happening automatically with a stand-alone toolbar.